# How to find the code matching the info from my memory dump?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jaxb, out-of-memory

I am currently analyzing a java heap dump from an OutOfMemory-crash. The Eclipse Memory Analyzer tells me as a "Problem Suspect 1":

> 650 instances of "java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry", loaded by "system class loader" occupy 650.000.120 (70,87%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Node[]", loaded by "system class loader"

As my application basically forwards SOAP messages, this is a bit much. When I look at details of one of the `java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry`, I see this:

```
Class Name                                                                       | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x367f81f8                                       |           32 |     1.014.040
|- <class> class java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x102fbe20 System Class         |            0 |             0
|- next java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x2c704810                               |           32 |     1.014.040
|- before java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x367f81c8                             |           32 |     1.014.040
|- key java.lang.Integer @ 0x367f8218  10229822                                  |           16 |            16
|- value java.util.Collections$SingletonList @ 0x367f8228                        |           16 |     1.013.992
|  |- <class> class java.util.Collections$SingletonList @ 0x102ab688 System Class|            8 |             8
|  |- element org.apache.cxf.headers.Header @ 0x367f8238                         |           24 |     1.013.976
|  |  |- <class> class org.apache.cxf.headers.Header @ 0x1c7785e0                |            8 |             8
|  |  |- name javax.xml.namespace.QName @ 0x1352e800                             |           24 |            24
|  |  |- direction org.apache.cxf.headers.Header$Direction @ 0x1c913610          |           16 |            72
|  |  |- dataBinding org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding @ 0x367f8250            |          104 |     1.013.768
|  |  |- object org.*************************.std.PayloadManifest @ 0x368f02f8   |           16 |           184
|  |  '- Total: 5 entries                                                        |              |              
|  '- Total: 2 entries                                                           |              |              
|- after java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry @ 0x368f5bb8                              |           32 |     1.014.040
'- Total: 6 entries                                                              |              |              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Therefore, I am looking for a map containing 650 instances of `JAXBDataBinding`, each one MB in size. The map should have an `Integer` as the key and a `java.util.Collections$SingletonList` as the value.

I searched for usages of `JAXBDataBinding`, only one finding. So, my best guess is a line where I call

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(header, Collections.singletonList(manifestHeader));
```

with header of type `String` and manifestHeader of type `org.apache.cxf.headers.Header`. Inside the manifestHeader is the `JAXBDataBinding`. So this fits. But `getRequestContext()` returns a `Map<String Object>` and not a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Collections$SingletonList>`.

This looks like a dead end.

I also looked at the stacktraces of the threads at the time the heapdump was written, but they do not look suspicious, mostly Jaxb-networking.

So, my questions are:

- Is there another way to find the culprit of the OutOfMemory-error from the heapdump?
- Is there maybe somehow a way where the `String` that is put into the `LinkedHashMap` above is getting saved as an `Integer`?
- Can I somehow modify my code or the way my application is run to give me more (necessary) details on this issue?

Comment: After some digging in the repo, I found some old code where this memory dump would make perfect sense - but this old version was never officially released. So we are now looking at our processes on how this could have happenend. Thus, the focus is no longer on the technical side. But we are still not sure about what happened.